# Android Viewpager Embed Youtube link

Tags: android, video, android-fragments, youtube

I have a viewpager that will show a video from youtube and images from other link.
My Question is, how to do  it?
Is there any good solution for this problem?
What I want is, the video on the first fragment and when the user click it, it'll play the video on fullscreen.
If there's no link from youtube, the first fragment is gone.
And the other fragment is a picture from other link.

Thanks before

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewPager often comes with Fragment, so consider to use a Fragment to add your Youtube Video, then add that Fragment in your ViewPager/ViewPager Adapter.

In detailed: define your xml layout and a Fragment that use that layout. it helps you to control where to put your video and your image.

In your activity that uses the ViewPager, initiate your Fragment, add stuff and then add that Fragment into your ViewPager.

Comment: So, I need to put something on one of the fragment and use it to show the video?

Comment: The general idea is to add any view you want in your Fragment layout. In this case, your view should be a SurfaceView to store/play your video or a more specific VideoView that will handle your video. So far you have to find out how to use VideoView to play a video, but it should be in another question.

Comment: Any Working examples can i get ?

Comment: @Ramesh_D what do you want to obtain? working examples depend on your use case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624454/viewpager-and-youtubeplayer/32245592. I implemented it worked !.. no example needed!